# Manipulate Word Documents in OS X with Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, automation, ms-word

I want to take an existing Microsoft Word document, and add bolding to certain words. Is it possible to do this using the MRI Ruby that comes pre-installed on OS X plus some gems? (Unfortunately, that rules out using JRuby, as suggested by [How to parse word documents with ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375861/how-to-parse-word-documents-with-ruby) )

I checked RubyGems.org searching for "word", and only came across word2html, which isn't relevant.

I checked Ruby Toolbox. "word" didn't get any relevant hits, and "Microsoft word" got massaji, rwv2, cat-bizdoc, and msworddoc-extractor, which aren't relevant.

I looked up rb-appscript. The [home page for appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) itself says it's no longer developed or supported. It suggests osascript or NSAppleScript, or two other solutions that lacked hyperlinks. osascript is described as being used by Ruby via the IO class - ie the command line. NSAppleScript is described as able to be used by Ruby via RubyCocoa. RubyCocoa is described as somewhat obsolete, with MacRuby being [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695353/38765) as an alternative. Installing MacRuby for the task in mind is overkill.

I've probably misunderstood something, but if so, what?

The operating system version would probably be OS X Snow Leopard or slightly newer or older.

I have access to a Windows machine, but that'd be a less preferred solution.

Comment: maybe this helps for `.docx` files:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885425/how-to-edit-docx-with-nokogiri-and-rubyzip

Comment: on windows you may have a look into `win32ole` from the stdlib.